# mysql calls from PHP server works intermittently (only after user log-in)

Tags: php, pdo

I have a windows-based Apache server (XAMPP) with mysql db connections implemented using PHP. I get this error when the system tries to connect to mysql locally or remotely. Interestingly, when I login to the server, it works just fine for the next couple of hours, then issue is back awaiting for another login. XAMPP is configured as service and the user is system..

**SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond**

Here is the code I am using

```
$dbConnection = NULL;
try{
    $dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=10.100.10.100; dbname=dbName", 'username', 'password');
    $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $statement = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * from `table` WHERE `date` = '2022-01-31';");
    $statement->execute();
    $PendingRequest = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                
    $dbConnection = NULL;


    return json_encode(["status"=>"Good", "data" => $PendingRequest], true);
}
catch (Exception $e) {

    $dbConnection = NULL;
    return json_encode(["status"=>"error","data"=>"", "message"=>$e->getMessage()], true);
}
```

I appreciate any comments on this issue.

Comment: You're using PDO, not PHP-MySQLiDB. Why do you have that tag?

Comment: It sounds like some kind of firewall issue, where logging into the server temporarily opens the port in the firewall.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had the issue originally with mysqli , then I changed the code to pdo hoping that it resolves the issue, but it didn't :(.

Comment: The error says that the server isn't responding. Why would changing from mysqli to PDO affect the server?

Comment: You already asked this question. Please don't repost it's pointless. Just edit the one you already asked

Comment: @Dharman It is closed. It said debugging details is required. that is why i added this. I couldn't edit the old one. Maybe idk how to use stackoverflow.

Comment: There's an edit button under every post.

Comment: @Barmar idk. I know that changing from mysqli to pdo shouldn't make any difference but I was perplexed that it continue to work after i sign out of the server. I will check your suggestions bout ports..